# Query records through its belongs_to relation in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm hoping for a little clarification on the correct way of querying records through its belongs_to relation in Rails 4.

I would like to find all parts that have a specific category name.

I can make it work with category ID using: `Part.where(category_id: "1")`

But I can't get it to take with the name.

If I do this:

```
Part.joins(:categories).where("categories.name = 'cars'").first
```

I get back this error:

> ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'categories' was not found on Part; perhaps you misspelled it?

I don't see where I misspelled anything and I can't figure out why it's not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Category Model:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parts
end
```

Parts Model:

```
class Part < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
end
```

Category Table:

```
CREATE TABLE categories
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name character varying(255),
  CONSTRAINT categories_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Parts Table:

```
CREATE TABLE parts
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  category_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT parts_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `belongs_to` association name is singular (which is correct, as it the standard) in the `Part` model, but you tried to join using the pluralized association name (you tried `:categories`). A common mistake; you probably got mixed up between the database naming convention, and the rails association naming convention. Try instead this:

```
Part.joins(:category).where('categories.name = "cars"').first
```

**Side note**:
This is not related to the question, but in case you did not already know, you can use a hash in the where clause if you like as well. It would look like:

```
where(categories: {name: "cars"})
```

And the result would be the same. In your case, it is not relevant since you're clearly passing a literal string, but it may come in handy when you're using form data, or something equally non-secure, since the hash method will properly treat the parameter as text, rather than dangerously placing it in the query as-is.

Comment: I'm trying to get this working now - Part.where(categories: {name: "cars"}) But I keep getting back ::: Part Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "parts".* FROM "parts" WHERE "categories"."name" = 'cars'
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "categories" :::: Any ideas what could be causing that error?

Comment: @newUserNameHere You still need the `joins(:category)` part. Otherwise the `INNER JOIN` will not be performed, and SQL won't know what that `categories` reference means.

Answer (score 2):

Use: `Part.joins(:category)`

The association name you pass to `joins` should mimic your declaration of it: `belongs_to :category`. Here you use `:category`, so give `joins` the same symbol.